# Show hovered element above scrollbar

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I'm trying to make a sidebar shrink to only show 50px of its width.

On hover I want this specific link to expand showing its content.

You can see it working fine in this snippet below.

The problem is I need to enable `overflow-y:auto;` so if the sidebar is too long, a user can scroll it.

But once `overflow-y:auto` is added to `overflow-x:visible`, `overflow-x` no longer works!

Try it by uncommenting `overflow-y` then try to hover over any element.

What am I missing ?

```css
#parent{
 background:#ddd;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 height:100vh;
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#content{
  z-index:1;/*to makesure sidebar is above content*/
 background:yellow;
 flex:1 1 0%;
}
#sidebar{
 z-index:2;/*to makesure sidebar is above it*/
 width:50px;
 /*If i uncomment this, the hover effect will no longer works */
  /*overflow-y:auto;*/
  overflow-x:visible;
}

a{
  height:50px;
  background:#ccc;
  width:50px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:col;
}
a > *{
 flex:1 1 0%;
}
a:hover{
  min-width:100px!important;
  width:100x;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <a> <i>1</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>2</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>3</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    
    <a> <i>4</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>5</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>6</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    
    <a> <i>7</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>8</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>9</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    
    <a> <i>10</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>11</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>12</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    
    <a> <i>13</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>14</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>15</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    given lower z-index to makesure sibar is above     content
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you ask isn't really possible, overflow is a sort of *take it or leave it* property and scrollbars are part of OS / browser chrome - any fancy stuff you see done with scrollbars other than this is usually achieved through javascript.

That aside, here's a possibly viable alternative not using javascript:

What I've done is instead make the whole *page* scrollable, give the content a div child (`#subcontent`) and give it a property of `position: fixed;` keeping it at the top.

I've also added `overflow:auto;` and `height:100%;` to `#subcontent` so that it remains scrollable if the content overflows (I've added some filler text to test this). Now when you hover over the sidebar it scrolls, and when you hover over the content this scrolls instead.

The only problem with this is that you can see 2 scrollbars, which might look a bit odd - and when you get to the bottom of the content and keep scrolling, it scrolls the sidebar instead. But that's the sacrifice you have to make here and probably the only pure css / html solution to your problem.

Note that some of the other css properties that were already present may now be redundant and could be deleted but I'm not sure.

Hope this helps!

```css
#parent {
    background:yellow;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
#content {
    z-index:1; /*to make sure sidebar is above content*/
    flex:1 1 0%;
}
#subcontent {
    position:fixed;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
#sidebar {
    background:#ddd;
    z-index:2; /*to make sure sidebar is above it*/
    width:50px;
    overflow:visible;
}
a {
    height:50px;
    background:#ccc;
    width:50px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:col;
}
a > * {
    flex:1 1 0%;
}
a:hover {
    min-width:100px!important;
    width:100x;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <a> <i>1</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>2</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>3</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    
    <a> <i>4</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>5</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>6</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    
    <a> <i>7</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>8</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>9</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    
    <a> <i>10</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>11</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>12</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    
    <a> <i>13</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>14</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
    <a> <i>15</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="subcontent">given lower z-index to make sure sidebar is above  content
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, accusamus rationibus adversarium vix te, porro vocent in duo. Pro expetenda ullamcorper philosophia et, quodsi fuisset appellantur eu vix. Quo at assum mollis erroribus, sed id veri dicit. Eam prima blandit iudicabit at.
  </p>
  <p>
Ea vis meis impetus, moderatius dissentiunt cum at, eam ullum liber eruditi ne. Qui temporibus adversarium ex, te appetere constituam vix, te possim everti erroribus est. Mei tantas tibique ei, labore dolorum adversarium pro ex. Eius neglegentur et eam. Possit meliore mei an, has tale dico mediocritatem no. Purto singulis postulant vix cu.
  </p>
  <p>
Ei qui tibique repudiare mediocritatem, in vix diam velit delenit. Et recusabo suavitate dissentias duo, nam id noluisse repudiandae. At meis iisque eam, eos ex atomorum recteque consetetur. Esse nostro noluisse has ei, pro illum expetenda eu.
  </p>
  <p>
Vix ut disputando deterruisset, sea veritus hendrerit an. Ad has eius blandit adipisci, iuvaret eligendi omittantur ad quo. Eius dicta cu sea, et inciderint referrentur his. Modus equidem eum id, eum et dolorem incorrupte. Pri quas definitiones no, mei causae dignissim ex, pri epicurei inciderint an.
  </p>
  <p>
Te eos sale quas semper. Alia omittantur sed in, ea fuisset mnesarchum mei, omittam qualisque te quo. Pri ad tollit dissentiunt, malis theophrastus in pro. Natum bonorum in sed. Mei ad equidem admodum scripserit, in ius falli maiorum blandit.
  </p>
  <p>
Luptatum incorrupte te vel. Per tempor volumus comprehensam eu, pri iudico splendide in. Tation ornatus mea ea, quo ex inani repudiare. Qui ad malis sensibus, mel quot facer cu. Quidam vituperata duo no, cu vix reque maiestatis, libris principes sit ea. Duo no habemus explicari, ne quo tota conclusionemque, eu vel percipit reprehendunt.
  </p>
  <p>
Option pericula referrentur at vix, mea elitr mediocrem ei. At facete audiam habemus usu, detracto repudiare vix ne, ea commodo expetenda eos. Equidem referrentur ei eos, no sed audire appellantur. Nec ei dicam sapientem complectitur, est ex justo habemus inimicus. His ceteros delicata scriptorem id. Et saepe discere per, dolores laboramus prodesset sit an. Prima repudiare an his, vim tritani maluisset gloriatur te, cu eam suavitate constituam.
  </p>
  <p>
Usu id hinc nemore, ex ius invidunt perfecto, per eu animal admodum efficiantur. Ad tempor fuisset accommodare cum, cu pri oblique gubergren. Duo et omnium nusquam democritum. Et tritani mandamus sit. Iisque docendi corrumpit vel at, pri ei elit errem.
  </p>
  <p>
Ei qui quodsi iriure, sententiae reprimique his ei. Decore nullam et duo. Mutat scriptorem in vix, ei saperet platonem deseruisse nec. An hinc aperiam fuisset sed, vocibus vivendum ad usu. No eros feugait partiendo has. Ne modo mutat vis, id eam esse tractatos, quem pertinax consequuntur sit ut.
  </p>
  <p>
Ad facer elitr munere pri. Quo id aperiam vocibus, sint offendit ius id. Eu impetus convenire vim, nibh melius qui ad, omittam abhorreant id quo. In vix aliquip indoctum, eu facilisi postulant ius. Ea epicuri aliquando necessitatibus sed.
</p></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your answers, i ended up solving this problem by positing content of sidebar element as absolute on hover, and wrapping it with a relative wrapper to keep it in place.

```css
#parent{
 background:#ddd;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 height:100vh;
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0;
  margin:0
}
#content{
  z-index:1;/*to makesure sidebar is above content*/
 background:yellow;
 flex:1 1 0%;
}
#sidebar{
 z-index:2;/*to makesure sidebar is above it*/
 width:50px;
  /*overflow-x:visible; no longer needed !*/ 
  overflow-y:auto;
}

a{
  height:50px;
  background:#ccc;
  width:50px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:col;
}
a > *{
 flex:1 1 0%;
}
.wrap{
  position:relative;
  height:50px; /*prevent element from collapsing when its children is positioned absolute*/
}
a:hover{
  min-width:100px!important;
  width:100x;
  flex-direction:row;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>1</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>2</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>3</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>4</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>5</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>6</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>7</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>8</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>9</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>10</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>11</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>12</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>13</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>14</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
    <div class="wrap"><a> <i>15</i> <span class="title">Title</span> </a></div>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    given lower z-index to makesure sibar is above     content
  </div>

</div>
```